# How can I avoid duplicate legend in plotly and set title vertically in R?

Tags: r, plotly, legend, title

The code I am using is:

```
DF <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  Month = c("2019-Dec","2019-Dec",
            "2019-Dec","2019-Dec","2020-Jan","2020-Jan","2020-Jan", "2020-Jan"),
  Week = c(4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L),
  Cat = c("A", "B", "A", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A"),
  n = c(17L, 6L, 21L, 10L, 19L, 20L, 12L, 14L)
)

fig <- DF %>%
  split(DF$Month) %>%
  purrr::map(~{
    plot_ly(colors = c("A" = "red", "B" = "green", "C" = "blue", "D" = "black")) %>%
      add_bars(data = .x,
               x = .x$Week,
               y = .x$n,
               type = 'bar',
               split = .x$Cat,
               color = .x$Cat,
               legendgroup = .x$Cat) %>%
      layout(xaxis = list(showticklabels = FALSE, title = unique(.x$Month)))
  })

subplot(fig, shareY = TRUE, titleX = TRUE, margin = 0) %>% 
  layout(barmode = 'stack', showlegend =TRUE)
```

The problem I am facing here is the duplicate legend on right. And I also want the Month title vertically not horizontally.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a solution to avoid duplicate legend using `showlegend=FALSE/TRUE` with a parameter. I am not sure if plotly lets you rotate the axis title. But maybe you could play around with individual axis ticks, which can be rotated?

```
"%>%" <- magrittr::"%>%"

DF_grp <- DF %>%
  split(DF$Month)


p <- lapply(seq_along(DF_grp),function(idx) {
  show_legend <- switch(idx,
                        "1"=TRUE,
                        "2"=FALSE)
  
  plotly:: plot_ly(colors = c("A" = "red",
                              "B" = "green",
                              "C" = "blue",
                              "D" = "black")) %>%
    plotly::add_bars(data=DF_grp[[idx]],
                     x=~Week,
                     y=~n,
                     type="bar",
                     split=~Cat,
                     color=~Cat,
                     legendgroup=~Cat,
                     showlegend=show_legend) %>%
    plotly::layout(xaxis=list(showticklabels=F,
                              title=unique(DF_grp[[idx]]$Month)),
                   barmode="stack",
                   showlegend =TRUE)
})

p %>%
  plotly::subplot(shareY = TRUE,
                  titleX = TRUE,
                  margin = 0)
```

Comment: But this fails if I have another Month to consider. I mean if I have "2020-Feb" then I am getting duplication again. What would be the more generic solution? Thanks for the answer =)

Comment: same solution. just adapt the `switch` or use something like `ifelse(idx==1,TRUE,FALSE)`